# How can i push message while client not visit my site?

Tags: push-notification, service-worker

I use serviceWorker to push client desktop notification. Clients receive message if they visit my site, how can Clients not visit can still receive the message(like onesignal.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Clients/Users don't have to be on your site to receive notification.

But your client/user has to accept the notification request in your site at first, so you save the subscription object in your database and later you use that user subscription data to send notification to your client/user at any time using library like [Web Push API](https://github.com/web-push-libs).

If you need anything in particular, please be specific.

Comment: Im using socket.io to push notification to client desktop. how can i broadcast a message if client don't connected?